# Повторяющийся элемент без JS

Tags: css, css3, dom, css-animation

Подскажите, возможно ли создать повторяющийся элемент `DOM` дерева без `JS` (тоесть он только визуально должен отображаться)? Приведу пример

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.weapper {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.block {
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*   animation: nudge 8s linear infinite; */
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-reflect: left;
  /* Можно ли это поместить в :before ? */
}

.element:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 572px;
  height: 70px;
}

.element img {
  margin: 0 31px;
}

@keyframes nudge {
  0% {
    transform: translatex(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatex(100vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="weapper">

  <div class="block">
    <div class="element">
      <img src="https://www.webspark.ua/img/header/ticker-img-1.png" width="100" height="75" alt="auto">
      <span>Текст который будет повторяться</span>
      <img src="https://www.webspark.ua/img/header/ticker-img-2.png" width="100" height="75" alt="soldiers">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Необходимо, что бы элементы, которые находяться в контейнере `element` повторялись, что слева от него что с права. Хотел применить свойства `-webkit-box-reflect: left;` `-webkit-box-reflect: right;` на псевдоклассы `:before :after`, а потом отразить отраженные элементы, но они почему-то не смогли подтянуть правильное решение.

- Вариант сделать картинкой, и потом через `background-repeat: repeat-x;` не предлагайте =)

Comment: Чего вы велосипед изобретаете, используйте JS и всё :)

Comment: В seo сообществе бытует поверие, что при анализе сайта бот-сканер не любит индексировать повторяющиеся элементы... будь-то текст, ссылки и тд. Для этого нежилательный к индексированию контент на странице скрывают в теневой дом сборки. Я клоакингом не занимаюсь, но с научной точки зрения интересно изучить возможности.